# When we need to use <!-- ko -->

Tags: knockout.js

What situation we should use the<"!--ko--"> and <"!--/ko--">" to cover the code.

Because in normal situation I just use data-bind in tag. But I always see the <"!--ko --"> in many code. But I really do not know what is that means and why we use this.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time it's just a personal or code-style preference. In some cases, one or the other is required. For example, sometimes there isn't a valid enclosing element for a set of html:

```
<tr>
    <td>Row header</td>
    <!-- ko foreach: rows -->
        <td data-bind="text: rowValue"></td>
    <!-- /ko -->
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some situations that you don't have any container element to use your data-binding tag. For example you have a `ul` and `li` but you need to have a fixed default `li` for your `foreach` or you need to have a default option in your select binding, in that case `the containerless control flow syntax` comes handy.

Example :

```
<ul>
    // Blow "li" is fixed with a different class
    <li class="fixed-title">Title</li>
    <!-- ko foreach: Items -->
        <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Some more examples here may be useful  (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html)